# Getting the innerhtml of td from string [JS]

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets say I have the following string:

```
var string = "<td>123</td><td>asd</td>";
```

I want to take the values of the td's and put them in an array. I tried using the foreach function but my regex stops after the first closing td and gets everything between < and >.

```
var regex = '<([^<> ]*)([^<>]*)?>([^>]*)<\/([^<>]*)>';
var string = "<td>123</td><td>asd</td>";
var result = string.match(regex);

result.forEach(function($var){
    console.log($var);
});
```

Output:

```
<td>123</td>
td
undefined
123
td
```

I need to manipulate the values so I can work directly in the foreach function without first splitting to an array.

Can I make this work with a regex? I can't use jQuery or append the string to the html.

Comment: Your `regex` variable just contains a string, not a `RegExp` object. You need to delimit it with `//` or use `new RegExp` to create a RegExp

Comment: var str = str.replace('<td>','') and then var res = str.split("</td>");?

Comment: @dwana I'm not sure if my td's will have classess or styles so I can't be sure replace will take all the right results

Comment: it's best not to use RegExp to process HTML. You should use an HTML DOM parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex alone to parse DOM is a no-no. However..

If you don't have nested `<td>` you can use the following code to get an array of values:

```
var string = "<td>123</td><td>asd</td>";
var tds = string.split("</td>");
var values = [];

for(var i=0; i<tds.length-1; i++){ //last element is empty if you split like this
    values.push(tds[i].substr(4)); //ommit the "<td>"
}

alert(values);
```

More complex structures could be a problem and I would advise you to break the TDs up to separate ones and then extract the values using regex (`/<td>(.*)</td>/g` and select group 1). But for this example it works fine.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CwzP/)

Comment: works great but I want to give the string as a whole row meaning ex.
"<tr><td>value</td></tr>" and that way the first value is <td>value

Comment: then just get rid of the tr wrapper, either by taking out a substring or by regex

Comment: of course not.. it's substr(4).. this is for empty tds.. doesn't matter though, this approach is wrong all together - you shouldn't parse DOM with regexes an substrings as I mentioned because of things like this..

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code,

```
> var re = /[^<>]+(?=<\/)/g;
undefined
> var result = string.match(re);
undefined
> result.forEach(function($var){
... console.log($var);
... });
123
asd
> console.log(result);
[ '123', 'asd' ]
```

**Explanation:**

- `[^<>]+` Matches any character not of `<` or `>` one or more times.
- `(?=<\/)` Lookahead asserts that anything following must be `</`

Answer (score 0):

Split the string with any of `<td>` OR `</td>` and reject the `""`.

This will work for you

```
var string = "<td>123</td><td>asd</td>";
var contents = string.split(/<td>|<\/td>/);
contents = contents.filter(function(el){return el != ""})

console.log(contents) //["123","asd"]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Do not parse HTML using RegExp!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1051677)

Here is a jQuery version for your problem:

```
$("<tr/>").append("<td>123</td><td>asd</td>") // build a row with the cells
.find("td") // get the cells
.map(function() { return $(this).text(); }); // for each cell, get the content
```

Result: `["123", "asd"]`

**Edit**: I see you can't use jQuery, that's unfortunate because you really need a DOM parser, and jQuery is just elegant and can do much more.

Answer (score 0):

**Avoid parsing HTML/XML with regex!**

I figured out a plain way with JavaScript to do it:

```
function extractValues(code)
{
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML = code;
    var tds = values.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
        values.push(tds[i].innerHTML);
    }

    return values;
}

console.log(extractValues("<td>123</td><td>asd</td>"));
```

If you realy realy want a regex, use this:

```
/<td>((?:.(?!<\/td>))*.?)<\/td>/g
```